# Is it possible to split datatable js by date (past, now, future) with option of expanding and collapsing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to get effect like shown in this mockup. I am using `https://datatables.net/` and now I ma considering sorting it on the backend side and return three dictionaries in JSON like `{'past': [], 'today': [], 'future': []}` but I think it should be possible with datatable js, let me know if it is, and some suggestions how to do it (using sorting is obvious), but I don't know how to do split and expand colapse. Thanks in advance for support!

[image]

UPDATE:

For now I go so far: http://jsfiddle.net/andilab/9pMbV/

I am able to group it by dates. How to split it into groups: PAST, TODAY, FUTURE?
My only idea is to return additional field calculated in backend determining in which group the record should be and then make grouping based on this value.

BUT I will apriciate any hack in JS for this problem, so that grouping based on extra calculated on client side parameter (determining T, P, F) will be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the row grouping add-in. I think this page may help you out https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/collapsibleGroups.html

Edit: For splitting the groups, you could add a column in the backend and apply the past, now and future labels dynamically.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I found also this: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html